# The simplest heat engine

Tags: thermodynamics, mesoscopic-physics

Heat engines are one of the concepts we are taught in school. We discuss Carnot engine, and various types of engine cycles and we calculate efficiency and the work produced by them.

We are also shown old car engines as examples. I'm more interested in what would constitute the simplest example of an engine at atomic scale (maybe mesoscopic if atomic is too small). Is there a simple theoretical model for such thing?

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to mind would be a [Brownian Ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_ratchet). Based on the idea of a ratchet-pawl mechanism connected to a paddle-wheel mechanism immersed in a fluid medium. The idea is that the random motion of the particles will move the blades back and forth, keeping the blades in the same position *on average* but since the ratchet only moves in one direction, work can be generated from the system.

Of course for this to work, the mechanism would have to be incredibly small, incredibly light, and incredibly responsive to individual atomic impacts.

> Feynman demonstrated that if the entire device is at the same temperature, the ratchet will not rotate continuously in one direction but will move randomly back and forth, and therefore will not produce any useful work. The reason is that since the pawl is at the same temperature as the paddle, it will also undergo Brownian motion, "bouncing" up and down.
>
> ...
>
> If, on the other hand, T2 is less than T1, the ratchet will indeed move forward, and produce useful work. In this case, though, the energy is extracted from the temperature gradient between the two thermal reservoirs, and some waste heat is exhausted into the lower temperature reservoir by the pawl. In other words, the device functions as a miniature heat engine, in compliance with the second law of thermodynamics. Conversely, if T2 is greater than T1, the device will rotate in the opposite direction.

Comment: I remember reading this long ago, in high-school. Feynman is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Well think of it from a statistical mechanics point of view. Theoretically, any system that takes energy to move and generates energy in return can constitute an engine. Taking this system, because of the laws of thermodynamics, the second law in particular, you should be able to format your system so that it makes use of the pressure differences between a hot/cold reservoir in order to move the energy-making device and create energy, and you would have an engine! However, the efficiency is this device is most likely what you would immediately question; In particular:

- Is it easy to produce
- Is it efficient in the sense of not only the classical efficiency equation, of low enough energy intensity to produce to make it worthwhile
- can it scale easily

As far as engines go, modern electrical and heat engines all seem to have a leg up on mesoscopic or microscopic engines